# Constructors not setting this pointer to const causes undetected issues

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, this-pointer

Cutting my classes to the bare-minimum for readability:

```
#ifndef MESSAGEFOLDER
#define MESSAGEFOLDER

#include <string>
#include <set>

class Message;

class Folder{
public: 
    void addMsg(Message* m) { messages.insert(m); } 
    ~Folder() { removeFromMessages(); }
private:
    std::set<Message*> messages;
    void removeFromMessages(); //removes its pointers from Messages
};

class Message{
    friend class Folder;
public:
    Message(const std::string &s = ""): contents(s) { }
    Message(const Message& rhs): contents(rhs.contents), folders(rhs.folders) { addToFolders(); }
    Message& save(Folder&); 
    ~Message() { removeFromFolders(); }
private:
    std::string contents;
    std::set<Folder*> folders;
    void addToFolders();
    void removeFromFolders(); //removes its pointers from Folders
};


#endif // MESSAGEFOLDER
```

In MessageFolder.cpp

```
void Message::addToFolders(){
    for(const auto& f : folders)
        f->addMsg(this);
}

Message& Message::save(Folder& f){
    folders.insert(&f);
    f.addMsg(this);
    return *this;
}
```

This code could cause some "problems" (albeit everything runs fine) when defining `const` versions of `messages`. The constructors for `Message` do not assume `const` of the `this` pointer. So even though `addToFolders` is a non-`const` function the code

```
Message a("hello");
Folder f;
a.save(f);
const Message b(a);
```

would compile fine. There is an issue here because `b` is a `const` message but the copy-constructor sets `b`'s address (through `addToFolders()`) to a Folder consisting of a `set` of `Message*` - the low-level `const` is lost. Indeed if I were to then define a function in `Folder` which changed the underlying messages I could change the `contents` of the const Message `b` seemingly with no compile error.

A solution would be to change the `Folder`'s set to `set<const message*>` but this disallows me to change messages through the folders (which I do actually desire). How would I prevent const objects of `message` being created or, even better, force that the `this` pointer in the constructors is `const` so that `addToFolders()` would fail?

Comment: I couldn't get much of the question. However, one thing is certain - const is never lost, unless const_cast specifically. It doesn't matter which way you go - if something was defined const, it will remain const.

Comment: You are right that the object is not `const` while being constructed. It remains undefined behaviour to modify a `const` object once its lifetime has started (after the constructor). But your use of `addToFolders` seems dubious anyway - especially since you don't have a destructor to remove it again.

Comment: @Alan Stokes I do have a destructor, I'll add it back in. I removed a lot for readability.

Comment: @AlanStokes, it is only an undefined behavior if the object was const_cast. Otherwise, it is well defined, and results in a compilation error. I am still trying to understand the problem, and I still cant.

Comment: @SergeyA Modifying a const object is always undefined behaviour, regardless of how you achieve it. This code shows an example where it does not generate a compilation error. (In `const X x;`, the constructor for X has no way of telling that the instance will be const, and it is possible to get a non-const pointer or reference to it without any cast.)

Comment: @AlanStokes, Ok, I finally got it. Thanks for explanation. The solution to authors problem is to follow well-known rule of not using this pointer in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent `const` instances being constructed.

If you use `this` in your constructor it is up to you to be suitably careful - you can explicitly `const_cast` it to a `const *`, for example.

Generally it works better if the management of the object is not handled within the object's own class. For example, you could restrict things so that the object can only be created via a `folder`, and the `folder` can then ensure it is handled correctly. (This is really just an example of separation of concerns.)